# jquery QuickFlip 2 image wont work properly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am using the Quickflip 2 plugin (http://jonraasch.com/blog/quickflip-2-jquery-plugin/comment-page-3#comment-3562), I have an image, when clicking on image it should show you the larger image. and there is anchor tag with "click here", by clicking on that it should flip the image and on the back it should have some info about that image. this is my code:

```
<li>
   <div class="quickflip-wrapper">
      <div>
         <p>This is a chocolate cake</p>
         <a href="#" title="number1" class="quickFlipCta" >
            <p>Go back to picture</p>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div>
         <a href="images/cake/1.JPG" rel="lightbox[gallery]" title="number1">
            <img src="images/cake/tumb/1.JPG" alt="">
         </a>
         <a href="#" class="quickFlipCta">
            <p>Read More About this cake</p>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

its works, but the layout is not what I wanted. here is the picture of what is it like.

[image]

and this is when flipping:

[image]

this is how they should be:

[image]

can someone explain what is going wrong here.

Comment: Your markup and question don't make a lot of sense. The first div within your quickflip wrapper should be content that is first presented, and the second div is the content after it is flipped. Also, your first cake looks a lot more like a chocolate cake than the second cake.

Comment: for some weird reason, the second div is the content at is first presented, The first div is the content after it is flipped. by clicking on read more about, then you should be able to see this is a chocolate cake. I got them from the website of jquery QuickFlip 2. I used it to exactly as it is there. the first image is of a chocolate cake, and the second image is when the chocolate image has flipped. the 3rd image is the way layout should be, without those brown line that are coming from the top.

Comment: maybe because your cakes are too sweet :P

Comment: I'm just thinking about cake now. Can you put a full version of the page that replicates the problem somewhere?

Comment: i have around 25 pic, that I am going to use the same effect for, I tried it with the first one and the result turned out to be not what I expected. as you can see from the images the first image has these parallel brown lines that are coming from the top, the last image is the image of what I have without the flip effect as, you can see there is no extra lines and anything like that. also i get the content of second div first and the the first div second which is weird.

Comment: Looks like a floating issue, difficult to say without seeing the whole code.